# When using GLSurfaceView, all other Android views are displayed as black rectangle

Tags: android, glsurfaceview

When using GLSurfaceView, all other Android views are displayed as black rectangle, no rendering happens for any other views other than the GLSurfaceView. How to fix this?

Comment: This isn't something that's routinely experienced while using `GLSurfaceView`, so you're going to have to go into much more detail. Please add a screenshot and the relevant code. Also, does the app still respond to user input events? And how often is `onDrawFrame()` executing?

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed by setting MainActivity background to have some solid color. It is transparent by default and the other views isn't rendered.